# Interpret RTF on server and echo the result in HTML tags, re-using bold, italic, ul and lists

Tags: php, html, echo, rtf

I've been crawling the web for days now and couldn't find exactly what I'm looking for. So hopefully someone here has an answer.

I'd like to build a webpage that is able to interpret an .rtf document on the server and then echo the text in the browser re-using only the bold, italic, underlined tags and bulleted and numbered list tags. Preferably using PHP, but if it's something else, that would be fine (I'd just have learn that language then a bit too, I guess).

Many thanks in advance!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an [RTF to HTML class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1930-PHP-RTF-to-HTML-converter-with-latin-character-support.html) on PHPClasses... no idea how goo dit is though.

Comment: Thank you. I still have to figure out how this works, but it seems promising.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/). It's a text to HTML format very similar to what you find here on StackOverflow.

There are several PHP ports. I suggest [PHP Markdown](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately this seems to be concerning a conversion from plain text. I'm looking for a conversion from RTF. Nevertheless, thanks for taking the time!